# Question about Audio signal trace layout (TLV320AIC3204)

Tags: pcb, audio, pcb-design, analog, trace

I am using the TLV320AIC3204 in an audio project.  The part is a stereo audio codec from TI.  I'm curious about how the traces are to be laid out.

With other chips such as the AD1939, you need to lay the ADC and DAC lines out as differential traces since the signals coming out of the chip are differential.

With the TLV320AIC3204, the signals appear to be single ended and have their respective Left and Right channels.  Now because of the way I have to lay out the board, I'm having issues with the audio signals "crossing" so I need to go to a different layer to sort the signals out.  I have two of these situations and i've solved them as shown below.

[image]

Is this okay with single ended audio signals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - that should be fine.  The capacitor formed between the two traces where they cross will be of negligible capacitance at audio frequencies.